# VAGRANT ERROR Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Tags: vagrant

I am using MacOSbigsur, Macbook Pro, M1 Chip,

I installed Virtual box the latest version 6.1.26r145957, use this command for confirmation (VBoxManage --version).

I installed Vagrant 2.2.18, use this command for confirmation (Vagrant --version).

I clone the repo from https://box.scotch.io/, and then type on terminal "vagrant up"

Following an error occurs, I try many solutions available on the internet but not fixed. I uninstall both software and re-install did not work for me, permission is ok from system preference.

There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...

Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE

VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter

VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open
/dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory

VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component

HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface

VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp

Possible Solution: sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart

when I run this command its shows the following errors

Loading VBoxDrv.kext

Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e

Error: Failed to load org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv
Loading VBoxUSB.kext

Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e

Error: Failed to load org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB
Loading VBoxNetFlt.kext

Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e

Error: Failed to load org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt
Loading VBoxNetAdp.kext
Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e

Error: Failed to load org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp

Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil unload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp

Error occurred unloading extensions: Missing extension with identifier org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp : Incompatible

architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e

Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil unload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt

Error occurred unloading extensions: Missing extension with identifier org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt : Incompatible

architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e
Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil unload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB
Error occurred unloading extensions: Missing extension with identifier org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB : Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e

Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil unload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv
Error occurred unloading extensions: Missing extension with identifier org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv : Incompatible architecture: Binary is for x86_64, but needed arch arm64e

Fatal error: VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error.

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp

Was able resolve simply by going to security settings and adding allow from Oracle.

For me this occurred after updating Mac OS, Oracle VB and Vagrant. Currently on Mac Os Monterey 12.3.1

[image]